# Windows update error 0x80070643 (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have been up since the morning trying to figure this out so I'm going to have to just throw this question up here and hope someone can help me with this problem...

After downloading the update, the updater then switches to "installing updates...", it stays at 0% then throws this error:

Security Update for SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 GDR (KB4019089) - Error 0x80070643

I have googled this problem, there are very little results which I have tried over and over but no matter what I always end up stuck on this update and this same exact error each time.

Only thing I can think of is a manual installation of this update but I'm not sure which one it is or how to do it. I tried the manual installation and still get "Failed" at the very last window of the wizard. Maybe I was doing it wrong. It has a lot of options and tick boxes which I just don't understand at this time.

Comment: "but I'm not sure which one it is or how to do it. " -  The update is KB4019089 and it is located in the same location every KB update is located at the [Microsoft®Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4019089) but you should verify the update is even applicable to your SQL Server 2016 installation.

Comment: [Verify your file versions before you attempt to install this update and edit your question to supply the required information.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019089/description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2016-service-pack-1).  Please format it.  [KB4019089](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55727)

Comment: @ramhound what do you mean by verify the update is applicable? This is the update that is automatically being assigned to me through the windows service.

Comment: @ramhound I will format it as soon as I know what I'm doing here. How do I verify my file versions? Also, what information do you need exactly once I reformulate the question...? I apologize if I come across as too unknowledgeable here but, like I said, this has me completely stumped as of right now.

Comment: View the properties of the file.  "lso, what information do you need exactly once I reformulate the question.." - The versions of the actual dll files, don't worry about the text documents, for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm so sorry, the properties of which file exactly? And which dll files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68757/discussion-between-daniel-and-ramhound).

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Resetting Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/971058/how-do-i-reset-windows-update-components) following the official guide.

If you still have problems, try to [install the update manually](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55727) after that.